# Find all the "$a$" satisfying the Interior is $\varnothing$

Tags: general-topology

This question was written in my instructor's note.

$Q)$ Let's define the topological space $(\mathbb{R},T)$ like the below. $\overline A$ is the closure of $A$. Say $E_a:=\left \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid \left (x^2-1\right )(x-a)<0\right \}$.

$\overline A=\begin{cases}
A  & 0\in A, \\
A & \text{$0\not \in A$ and $A$ is finite,} \\
\mathbb{R} & \text{$0\not \in A$ and $A$ is infinite.}
\end{cases}$

Find the all the $a$ satisfying  $\operatorname{int}(E_a)=\varnothing$. ($\operatorname{int}(E_a)$ means interior of $E_a$).

I would suggest the two solutions of mine.

First solution) The open sets of the $(\mathbb{R},T)$ are $2^{\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}}\cup \{G\mid 0\in G\text{ and }G^c\text{ is finite}\}$.
For all the cases of $a$, whatever $a$ is, we can take $\operatorname{int}(E_a)=E_a\setminus \{0\}$. But since $E_a$ is the infinite set, $\operatorname{int}(E_a)\neq \varnothing$. So the answer is there are no $a$ such that $\operatorname{int}(E_a)=\varnothing$.

Second solution) $\operatorname{int}(E_a)=\varnothing \iff \overline{E_a}=\mathbb{R}\iff 0\not \in E_a^c$ and $E_a^c$ is infinite. Therefore, $0\in E_a$. The answer is $a<0$.

The results of the two solutions are contradictory at the point of the existence of $a$. The first solution claimed there aren't any $a$. On the other hand, the second solution claimed there are $a$ s.t. $a<0$. I can't find which solution is correct. Please let me know which solution is false, tell me the reason why it does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the closure operator doesn't define properly a topology, since it isn't monotone: $$\overline{(0,1)}=\Bbb R\text{ but }\overline{[0,1)}=[0,1).$$